# Как распознать все объекты на фото с помощью yolo?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети

Я собрал обучающих набор, где на 1 картинке только 1 объект, у меня получилось 8 классов. После обучения yolo она со 100% точность распознает объект на новой картинке, но только если там 1 объект, а как запустить распознавание так чтобы если например на картинке было 3 объекта, она распознала их всех, а не только 1 какой то(как происходит сейчас). Во время подготовки данных я не использовал аннотацию, не размечал объект на картинке